# Put sql join inside array on CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables, users and malls, with a column with the same name, name, and I want to join them but I would like to store the malls columns inside an array, kinda like this:

```
$this->db->select('users.id, users.name, malls.name, malls.url');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('users.id', $id);
$this->db->join('malls', 'malls.id = users.mall_id');
```

and have this as a result:

```
$user = array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Test user',
        'mall' => array('name' => 'Test mall', 'url' => 'blahblah.com')
    );
```

I've seen it on ORM like eloquent from laravel, but I want to use it on codeigniter with its ActiveRecord.

Comment: does it actually matter? You could write straight up sql?

Comment: What you explained isn't accomplished by a join, but using a two separate queries then building the object yourself. As for what you're currently after you can give the column an alias so you can access it so malls.name as mall_name in your select will let you have both in your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it is 'eager loading' and Codeigniter does not support that.